# How to ignore server cache-control and expires headers when using RestKit with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, caching, restkit, afnetworking-2, cache-control

I'm working on an app using backend server I have no control over. Server response have headers

```
"Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
Expires = "Fri, 20 Jun 2014 09:00:39 GMT";
```

among others, but both these values are wrong, the response should be cached for 15mins. I've searched and found what seems to be a solution to this, i.e. here [Bypassing http response header Cache-Control: how to set cache expiration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840688/bypassing-http-response-header-cache-control-how-to-set-cache-expiration)

But it's not working for me, - storeCachedResponse: forRequest: is never being called. I'm also setting NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad on a request.

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you verified that `setSharedURLCache:` is called and checked which cache RestKit is getting when it requests the cache to use?

Comment: Yes, I set the shared URL cache to my custom cache, I can verify that by logging from cachedResponseForRequest: method. But storing is never called, so every cache try is a miss!